# Swift - Getting data to transfer from one TableViewController to another once a date passes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm working on an app which it date based. I'm trying to get information to pass from one TableViewController to another.

It's a notification based app that reminds the user that something comes out today. So on the date it comes out, I'd like it to come off the release list and go onto the released list (So if something comes out the Nov.8th, on that date it'll be moved to the released list).

I'm having trouble getting it to work. Below is the code I used on the release list:

```
 let startOfToday = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()) as NSDate
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "release_date > %@", startOfToday)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

And here's the code on the released list:

```
 let startOfToday = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()) as NSDate
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "release_date < %@", startOfToday)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

Comment: What's not working? Explain what's happening.

Comment: Where is the data stored? Need more details

Comment: Currently, nothing happens when the date comes and goes, the information just stays on the release list.

Comment: data is stored in the fresh_release.xcdatamodeld